# VNC view distorted

Tags: raspbian, vnc

I'm running latest raspbian buster on a raspi 3, and launched a vncserver on it. Then connecting through remmina, the output is kind of grabled/distorted, see example. What could be the reason and how to fix it?[image]

Comment: @telcoM yes, that seems to have done the trick. Want to put it in an answer so I can accept and upvoe it?

Comment: I've done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like JPEG compression and other artifacts. In the VNC connection profile settings of `remmina`, which "Color depth" and "Quality" settings are you using?

At least on my Debian 10 system, the default Quality setting appears to be "Poor (fastest)" which might explain the distortions as the display data is aggressively compressed.